# How to add OAEPParameterSpec to a JWE object?

Tags: java, security, jwe, jose4j

I need to add an OAEPParameterSpec as a AlgorithmParameterSpec to a JWE (Json Web Encryption) object. How can I do that?

I'm using a client - server application. server is encrypting in RSA-OAEP-256 encryption algorithm, client is failing at decrypting it since it is using an HSM and there is a padding issue. A lot of researches shows that BouncyCastle provider has to be used in order to solve that but that isn't relevant for me because I can't change the HSM.

In order to have this there is a tweak should be done at server side before encrypting is to add the following line

```
AlgorithmParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
```

This "oaepParameterSpec" has to be added to the JWE object I'm using, but I can't find any reference to guide me how to do that nor in the jose4j specs on how to change/set AlgorithmParameterSpec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RSA-OAEP-256 implementation in jose4j uses that OAEPParameterSpec https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/src/2e8f0c3fe7fdc9c8c48a572e02a677fb16c21448/src/main/java/org/jose4j/jwe/RsaKeyManagementAlgorithm.java#lines-84 so I don't know if that path is going to help.

Comment: I've ran into that. but the issue here is that the encryption I have to do via JWE ( JsonWebEncryption ) object. I need to find a way how to link/init the JWE object with the RsaKeyManagementAlgorithm instance, which I can't figure out how.

Comment: The JsonWebEncryption object will use the KeyManagementAlgorithm implementation indicated by the alg header value in the JWE. Some example usage (kinda) in the tests https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/src/2e8f0c3fe7fdc9c8c48a572e02a677fb16c21448/src/test/java/org/jose4j/jwe/RsaOaepKeyManagementAlgorithmTest.java#lines-112 and https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/src/2e8f0c3fe7fdc9c8c48a572e02a677fb16c21448/src/test/java/org/jose4j/jwe/RsaOaepKeyManagementAlgorithmTest.java#lines-157